# Parse HTTP headers - encoding issue

Tags: http, character-encoding

I'm writing a tiny HTTP server using C++ (just for fun).

When receiving request from a client, should I worry about charset of HTTP headers? Is it guaranteed that all of them constist only of one-byte ASCII characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a great question and I don't know but would like to.  I believe you will find the answer here:  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

That doc says that Headers follow RFC822 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt) and that one says ASCII.  I'm thinking that you can rely upon the ASCIIness of it all.

Comment: It seems that you're right: "Each header field can be viewed as a single, logical  line  of ASCII  characters,  comprising  a field-name and a field-body." Thanks a lot!

Comment: The answer above is incorrect. RFC 2616 mentions RFC 822, but this is not a normative statement, just a reference to a prior, similar format. The ABNF in RFC 2616 makes it clear that you can have octets >= 128.

Answer (score 3):

*Is it guaranteed that all of them constist only of one-byte ASCII characters?*

No. HTTP uses TCP, so octets >= 128 can be transferred.

*Does HTTP allow non-ASCII characters?*

Yes. See the ABNF for field-content ([RFC 2616, Section 4.2](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.4.2)) and quoted-string ([RFC 2616, Section 2.2](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.2.2)).

*Does HTTP define the encoding?*

More or less, by stating that non-ISO-8859-1 characters require an additional layer of encoding (again, from 2.2):

> The TEXT rule is only used for descriptive field contents and values that are not intended to be interpreted by the message parser. Words of *TEXT MAY contain characters from character sets other than ISO-8859-1 [22] only when encoded according to the rules of RFC 2047 [14].

*Is this used in practice?*

Yes. For instance, in Content-Disposition.

*Is this a good idea?*

No, because many recipients and intermediates get this wrong.

Comment: I don't get it. According to this doc [rfc822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt) (BNF on the page 9, where CHAR is ASCII character). Do you mean custom headers?

Comment: Comrade - How is RFC 822 relevant?

Comment: In section 4.2 it calls out RFC 822:  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2 sounds to me like the standard is being ignored.

Comment: Methinks some reference is in order here.  Where have you seen non-ascii chars in headers and what spec are they following such that we can write some code around this.

Comment: Bob: "follow the same generic format" doesn't mean they are the same. RFC 2616 itself defines the format, and it definitely allows code points >= 128. I'm not saying it is a good idea, but it's what the spec says.

Re: "Where have you seen non-ascii chars in headers and what spec are they following such that we can write some code around this." - the spec is RFC 2616. Example header fields where I have seen non-ASCII are Content-Disposition (in the Filename parameter) and WWW-Authenticate (in the Realm parameter).

Comment: @JulianReschke, in section 4.2, rfc 2616 states [*"Header fields can be extended over multiple lines by preceding each extra line with at least one SP or HT"*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2). Does this mean that header field names (e.g.  `Cache-Control`, `User-Agent`, `Pragma`, `Connection`) can be split into multiple lines, and some of those *lines* could even contain just `CRLFSP`?

Comment: @JulianReschke, Cool =) <rant>building a proper HTTP parser just got 10x harder again.</rant>

Comment: @Pacerier: no, it was always as hard :-)